# Why is my Nativescript-vue release apk giving errors

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

My nativescript-vue app works well on my device when I run tns run android but when I create the release apk and install it, the app always crushes on startup with a message "unfortunately LGIapp has stopped". LGIapp is the name of my app. It is even on the playstore but all my test users have that same error. Kindly help I am really stack. Thanks

Comment: are you using `--bundle`?

Comment: I was following this post below : I think he forgot to add --bundle. I will add it and see if it works. Here is the post https://www.nativescript.org/blog/steps-to-publish-your-nativescript-app-to-the-app-stores#step-5

Comment: Please share the full error log.

Comment: @Manoj Sorry I didnt get any error logs in my google play console. Besides i already solved the problem by adding --bundle to the tns build android --release command. Thanks

Comment: @TiagoA. it worked!. Can you kindly post your comment as an answer so i can accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! I think tns will assume `--bundle` in the next versions. I see people stumbling in this every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `--bundle` even in release builds. Your build command should be:

```
tns build android --bundle --release
```

I think `tns` will assume `--bundle` in the next versions. I see people stumbling in this every day... Meanwhile, don't forget that `--bundle` :).